# Converting columns into matrix based on matches

Tags: perl, awk

I want to convert col1 and col2 into a matrix such that if A is occurring in any seq program should print *

```
Input file:
A   seq1
A   seq3
B   seq1
B   seq2
B   seq3
C   seq1
C   seq2
D   seq1

Required output:
        A   B   C   D
seq1    *   *   *   *
seq2        *   *
seq3    *   *
```

Comment: smells like a too broad question.

Comment: Split the input and put it into a hash, using `$hash{seq1}{A}++` to mark the matches. Then loop over the keys, printing which keys A-D contains a true value.

Comment: You have asked three questions and accepted none. This is not how SO works. If you have an open issue, leave a comment. If your issue is resolved click the check mark next to the answer so that it is green.

Comment: Sorry,  thought up-vote is the way to accept. Din't know that I have to click on the mark. i'll do that . Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it in `awk`

```
awk '{a[$1FS$2]="*";b[$1];c[$2]} END {printf "\t";for (j in b) printf "%s\t",j;print "";for (i in c) {printf "%s\t",i;for (j in b) printf "%s\t",a[j FS i];print ""}}' file
        A       B       C       D
seq1    *       *       *       *
seq2            *       *
seq3    *       *
```

Some more readable:

```
awk '
    {data[$1FS$2]="*"
    col[$1]
    row[$2]} 
END {printf "\t"
    for (j in col) 
        printf "%s\t",j
    print ""
    for (i in row) {
        printf "%s\t",i
        for (j in col) 
            printf "%s\t",data[j FS i]
        print ""}
    }' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl from command line,

```
perl -lane'
  $h{$F[1]}{$F[0]} = "*";
  $s{$F[0]}++ or push @r, $F[0]; 
END{ 
  $, = "\t";
  print "", @r;
  print $_, @{ $h{$_} }{@r} for sort keys %h;
}
' file
```

output

```
        A       B       C       D
seq1    *       *       *       *
seq2            *       *
seq3    *       *
```

Comment: This is nice. I was thinking HoA but HoH is easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my ( %hash, %hash1 );
open FD, "File_name";
while (<FD>) {
    if (/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/) {
        $hash1{$1} = 0;
        push @{ $hash{$2} }, $1;
    }
}

print "\t$_" foreach ( sort keys %hash1 );

foreach my $val ( sort keys %hash ) {
    $hash1{$_}++ foreach ( @{ $hash{$val} } );
    print "\n$val\t";
    foreach ( sort keys %hash1 ) {
        print "*\t" if ( $hash1{$_} != 0 );
        print "\t" unless ( $hash1{$_} != 0 );
    }
    $hash1{$_} = 0 foreach ( keys %hash1 );
}
```